# Xamarin UITest ScrollDownTo for Android is really slow

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, scroll, xamarin.uitest

When using Xamarin UITest to test my app I encounter very slow speeds for scrolling. I scroll using the ScrollDownTo method. When performing the method on iOS it works like a charm however, on the Android emulators the method takes a long time to perform the scroll.

Does anyone know how to speed this up?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of Xamarin.UITest  are you using? Does it help if you update to the latest supported versions?Besides, are you running your app on an emulator or a physical device? and what is the device model & OS version?

Comment: Any update on this? Physical samsung Galaxy A30, Android 10. Xamarin forms  4.8

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed this issue as well and it depends on the Android device. For any android device that is older with OS 7.x.x and under is about 5 to 6 times slower than any iOS device. Now with OS 8.x.x and higher if it's a Samsung Device the Scrolling takes forever however with a Pixel or other devices I see near close to the iOS performance. Android always seems to be slower than iOS and I am not sure as too why. This would be something the Xamarin team would need to look at

Answer (score 0):

In order to increase the speed of this scrolldownto method , we can try different combinations of default parameters
Try scroll strategy to Gesture and swipe speed to 2000